# Send custom messages to devices in a batch via APNS

Tags: java, ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm using [notnoop](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns/) APNS Java library to send APNS notifications. Since we have a big number of users, we need to send APNS notifications in batch. According to the notnoop API, the following method seems to be the best choice:

```
push(Collection<String> deviceTokens, String payload)
```

http://notnoop.github.com/java-apns/apidocs/com/notnoop/apns/ApnsService.html

This method send a single message to multiple devices in a batch. We want to send different specific message for each device but still send all of the notifications in a batch. I didn't find any proper methods in notnoop library to do this. Does anyone have experience on this? Is it possible to do this with notnoop library? Does Apple APNS server support this kind of pushing?

Thanks in advance!

Best,
J

Comment: is there any new support for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to iterate through your devices individually and build a separate payload for each of them. In this example, we pass a different badge count to every user:

Declare your ApnsService as a thread pool so the push goes fast

```
    ApnsService service = null;

        service = APNS.newService()
                .withCert(certificatePath, certificatePassword)
                .withProductionDestination()
                .asPool(threadCount)
                .build();


        service.start();
```

Build your payload base outside your device iteration

```
        PayloadBuilder payloadBuilder = APNS.newPayload();

        payloadBuilder = payloadBuilder
                .alertBody("yourMessage")
                .sound("default"));
```

Iterate through your devices and add the custom message or parameters

```
        for (ApnsDevice apnsDevice : apnsDeviceList) {
            try {
                PayloadBuilder perDevicePayloadBuilder = payloadBuilder.copy()
                        .badge(apnsDevice.getBadgeCount()+1);

                // check if the message is too long (it won't be sent if it is)
                //and trim it if it is.
                if (perDevicePayloadBuilder.isTooLong()) {
                    logger.warn("Payload is too long, shrinking it");
                    perDevicePayloadBuilder = perDevicePayloadBuilder.shrinkBody();
                }

                String token = apnsDevice.getDeviceToken();

                service.push(token, perDevicePayloadBuilder.build());

            } catch (Exception ex) {
               logger.error("Error while pushing apns alerts", ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: is there a reference to this library? or you just have to review the code?

Comment: The user asked a question regarding the notnoop library (https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns). For the rest, the ApnsDevice object is just an entity containing various information on the device that is stored in the DB, like the device token, the current badge count, the iOS version...